# Swift - checking enum type/value

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum structure for passing back either a data value or an error:

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

I also have an enum structure that looks like the following for sending back errors from our network layer:

```
public enum NetworkServiceError: String, Error {
    case jsonParsing = "Error parsing the json response from the server"
    case invalidUrlRequest = "Error forming the url request"
    case dataEncoding = "Error encoding the data"
}
```

The Result type is what gets passed back via a closure, something like the following:

```
completion(.failure(NetworkServiceError.invalidUrlRequest))
```

I am writing a test case, and I need to be able to check if that error was a certain type from the above enum.  To give you an idea of what I'm doing and where I want to check it, see the following example code:

```
networkClient.callAPI() { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success( _):
        // do something
    case .failure(let error):
        if error == NetworkServiceError.invalidUrlRequest { // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to how to go about in my case; I'm probably overlooking something very simple here.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation from https://github.com/antitypical/Result, you see that they make both the `Value` and `Error` types generic. That would allow the completion closure to know what type of error it's getting. Then the switch can match against the specific cases.

So if the closure got a `Result<Something, NetworkServiceError>` then the switch case could become

```
case .failure(.jsonParsing):
```

---

If you didn't want to change `Result` you could use a case like this to match a specific type of error

```
case .failure(let error as NetworkServiceError):
```

Comment: You can also use `case .failure(NetworkServiceError.jsonParsing)` with an untyped error `Result<T>`.